# How to add a background image in Angular 2 Component?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 2 app. In this app i have few components. I want to add a background image only to login component. How do i do that?

```
body{
    background-image: url('https://s.zkcdn.net/Advertisers/d36ea4926dfa4978ab2556ba7688692c.png') ;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    height:100%;

}
```

I have this style for the login component. but it's not covering the entire windows. it's covering only the form section.

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Answer (score 15):

I faced the same problem.But below code works good for me.

Add a following css code in global css file (style.css).

```
.bg-img
{
    background-image: url('/assets/images/back.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

and add the below code in ngOnInit section in required component.ts file.(ex:login.component.ts)

```
ngOnInit() {
    document.body.classList.add('bg-img');
}
```

Comment: This works, but somehow whenever I change the component, the background gets stuck until i refresh the page. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: You can remove the class on ngOnDestroy lifecyle-hook then it will not stuck whenever you change your component

Comment: @franpen or you can in component1: `document.body.classList.remove('bg-img-login');
    document.body.classList.add('bg-img-register');` and in component2: `document.body.classList.remove('bg-img-register');
    document.body.classList.add('bg-img-login');` And ofc, in parent component you have to remove both of them.

Comment: Mmm, but then you will have to remove it in every other component, which is not very practical.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard that’s the issue, I haven’t found a practical solution to this. Nevertheless, I’ll test your idea when I get home

Comment: @franpen look at @Suhel Khan's comment. You can destroy the image on `ngOnDestroy()`. This will prevent you from removing it manually in every component you route to.

Answer (score 3):

I am using angular 7. This is how I achieved full background image in a component.
in login.component.html

```
<div class="bg-img">

 </div>
```

then in the login.comonent.css

```
.bg-img{
 min-height: 100vh;
width: 100%;
background: url('../../../src/assets/loginimage.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `@Component` decorator of your login component, you can add a `styleUrls` field. Doing so will allow you to use a style sheet for your login component only.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'your-selector'
  templateUrl: ['path/to/your/html/component'],
  styleUrls: ['path/to/your/stylesheet'],
})
```

You can then, in your style sheet, change your background only for the `login` component

Comment: body{
        background-image: url('https://s.zkcdn.net/Advertisers/d36ea4926dfa4978ab2556ba7688692c.png') ;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        height:100%;

    }

Comment: I have this style for the login component. but it's not covering the entire windows. it's covering only the form section.

Comment: You could try to add a `div` encapsulating your body and set the background of this div. Not sure why you have this result, check how your components are one in another

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ionic 3. But Ionic uses Angular.

In my login.html page I have this:

```
<ion-content class="background">
 ...
</ion-content>
```

I think you can try with a:

```
<body class="background">
</body>
```

And in my login.scss page I have this:

```
page-login {
    .background {
        // Path of my picture
        background-image: url('../assets/background.gif');
    }
}
```

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

// in div father

```css
.bg-component {
    background-image: url('../../../assets/images/backgroundweb/layer-2-copy-2@3x.png') !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```